# Dynamically Override Fancy Title - Part II

Tags: wp-query, functions, query, php

I followed instruction by @pat-j and @cjbj in this answer: [Dynamically Override Fancy Title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263380/dynamically-override-fancy-title) and I got the result of override title. 
Now I need to dynamically change this title.
I have written this function:

```
add_filter ('presscore_get_page_title','netbooking_presscore_get_page_title',10,1);
function netbooking_presscore_get_page_title ( $title ) {

if(  is_page( '1057' ) ){

    $GLOBALS["content"] = $content;
```

// This reads input considering a default value in case of error

```
$INPUT = function($param, $default, $prefix = true){
            $key = $prefix ? 'netbooking_structure_'.$param : $param;
            return isset($GLOBALS["content"][$key]) ? $GLOBALS["content"][$key] : $default;
        };
```

// This read GET input

```
$language = $INPUT('language', 'it', false);
        $lang = substr($language, 0, 2);
        $upwd = $INPUT('upwd', '8UDW37tF', false);
        $cryptedID = $INPUT('crypted_id', 'Nel6LjH9xZ4=', false);
        $structure_id = $INPUT('sid', 268, false);
        $accomodation_id = $INPUT('aid', '4894', false);
```

// This calls and gets the XML with accomodation data

```
$today = getdate();
        $api = 'http://url';
        $query = http_build_query([
            'get' => 'getaccomodation',
            'upwd' => $upwd,
            'id' => $structure_id,
            'idacc' => $accomodation_id,
            'type' => 'p',
            'mode' => 'xml',
            'ukey' => 'create',
            'l' => $lang,
            'dstart' => $today['mday'],
            'mstart' => $today['mon'],
            'ystart' => $today['year'],
        ]);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($api. '?' . $query));
        $accomodation = $xml->accomodation;
    // Ottengo l'XML del prezzo della accomodation
    $api = 'http://netbooking.naturalbooking.it/getnbdata.php';
    $query = http_build_query([
        'get' => 'accomodationminprice',
        'upwd' => $upwd,
        'id' => $structure_id,
        'idacc' => $accomodation_id,
        'type' => 'p',
        'mode' => 'xml',
        'ukey' => 'create',
        'l' => $lang,
    ]);
    $priceData = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($api. '?' . $query));
```

// Here we get link for current accomodation

```
$link = 'http://url';
        $query = http_build_query([
            'cmd' => 'bookstep1',
            'id' => $cryptedID,
            'type' => 'p',
            'l' => $lang,
            'idacc' => $accomodation_id
        ]);
        $link = $link. '?' . $query;
```

// Local settings

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, $language);
```

// Get the title

```
    $accomodation->id;
    if ($accomodation){

          foreach($accomodation as $accomodation) {
         $title = $accomodation->name_struct." ".$accomodation->name;
         }
         }
    }   
  return $title;
         }
```

It always returns the name of the first accomodation in list instead of the current accomodation name.

**EDIT**
I identified the issue to be inside the get function. but I can't understand why the same inside a page template works, whereas inside the hook it doesn't work.
This is the last version of the function:

```
// ACCOMODATION TITLE
add_filter ('presscore_get_page_title','netbooking_presscore_get_page_title',10,1); // filtro che aggiunge la funzione per sovrascrivere il title
function netbooking_presscore_get_page_title ( $title ) { // title function
if(  is_page( '1057' ) ){ // conditional output

        global $content;
        $GLOBALS["content"] = $content;

        // This reads input considering a default value in case of error

        $INPUT = function($param, $default, $prefix = true){
            $key = $prefix ? 'netbooking_structure_'.$param : $param;
            return isset($GLOBALS["content"][$key]) ? $GLOBALS["content"][$key] : $default;
        };

        // Read GET input
        $language = $INPUT('language', 'it', false);
        $lang = substr($language, 0, 2);
        $upwd = $INPUT('upwd', '8UDW37tF', false);
        $cryptedID = $INPUT('crypted_id', 'Nel6LjH9xZ4=', false);
        $structure_id = $INPUT('sid', 268, false);
        $accomodation_id = $INPUT('aid', '4894', false);

        // Build XML Accomodation
        $today = getdate();
        $api = 'http://myurl.it';
        $query = http_build_query([
            'get' => 'getaccomodation',
            'upwd' => $upwd,
            'id' => $structure_id,
            'idacc' => $accomodation_id,
            'type' => 'p',
            'mode' => 'xml',
            'ukey' => 'create',
            'l' => $lang,
            'dstart' => $today['mday'],
            'mstart' => $today['mon'],
            'ystart' => $today['year'],
        ]);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($api. '?' . $query));

        // Imposto il locale
        setlocale(LC_TIME, $language);



$nomestruttura=(string)$xml->accomodation->name_struct;
$nome=(string)$xml->accomodation->name;

$title=$nomestruttura." ".$nome;

    }   
  return $title;
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it. The final version of the function is:

```
<?php 

// ACCOMODATION TITLE
add_filter ('presscore_get_page_title','netbooking_presscore_get_page_title',10,1);
function netbooking_presscore_get_page_title ( $title ) {
if(  is_page( '1057' ) ){

        $GLOBALS["content"] = $content;

        // This reads input considering a default value in case of error


$INPUT = function($param, $default, $prefix = true){
                $key = $prefix ? 'netbooking_structure_'.$param : $param;
                return isset($GLOBALS["content"][$key]) ? $GLOBALS["content"][$key] : $default;
            };

        // Read input GET
        $language = $INPUT('language', 'it', false);
        $lang = substr($language, 0, 2);
        $upwd = $INPUT('upwd', '8UDW37tF', false);
        $cryptedID = $INPUT('crypted_id', 'Nel6LjH9xZ4=', false);
        $structure_id = $INPUT('sid', 268, false);
        $accomodation_id = $INPUT('aid', '4894', false);

        // XML accomodation
        $today = getdate();
        $api = 'http://';
        $query = http_build_query([
            'get' => 'getaccomodation',
            'upwd' => $upwd,
            'id' => $structure_id,
            'idacc' => $accomodation_id,
            'type' => 'p',
            'mode' => 'xml',
            'ukey' => 'create',
            'l' => $lang,
            'dstart' => $today['mday'],
            'mstart' => $today['mon'],
            'ystart' => $today['year'],
        ]);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($api. '?' . $query));



        // Imposto il locale
        setlocale(LC_TIME, $language);

 $url="htp://";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$nomestruttura=(string)$xml->accomodation->name_struct;
$nome=(string)$xml->accomodation->name;

$title=$nomestruttura." ".$nome;

    }   
  return $title;
         }
         ?>
```

I understood the mistake is in the function to get the xml. Now I have to solve this.
**EDIT & SOLVED**

```
    // ACCOMODATION TITLE
add_filter ('presscore_get_page_title','netbooking_presscore_get_page_title',10,1); // filter for title
function netbooking_presscore_get_page_title ( $title ) { // function to override title
if(  is_page( icl_object_id('1057')) ){ // Conditional output with ICL support
// Added Query 

                global $wp_query; 

    // Get Values
    $content = [];
    $content["crypted_id"] =   get_option('netbooking_'.'home'.'_crypted_id_meta');
    $content["upwd"] =         get_option('netbooking_'.'home'.'_upwd_meta');
    $content["structure_id"] = get_option('netbooking_'.'home'.'_structure_id_meta');
    $content["language"] = netbooking_get_language();
    $content["sid"] = isset($_GET['sid']) ? $_GET['sid'] : $wp_query->query_vars['sid'];
    $content["aid"] = isset($_GET['aid']) ? $_GET['aid'] : $wp_query->query_vars['aid'];
    foreach ($GLOBALS['structure'.'-options'] as $key => $option) {
        $content[$key] = get_option($key);
}


        $GLOBALS["content"] = $content;

        // Function to read default values in case of error
        $INPUT = function($param, $default, $prefix = true){
            $key = $prefix ? 'netbooking_structure_'.$param : $param;
            return isset($GLOBALS["content"][$key]) ? $GLOBALS["content"][$key] : $default;
        };

        // GET Input
        $language = $INPUT('language', 'it', false);
        $lang = substr($language, 0, 2);
        $upwd = $INPUT('upwd', '8UDW37tF', false);
        $cryptedID = $INPUT('crypted_id', 'Nel6LjH9xZ4=', false);
        $structure_id = $INPUT('sid', 268, false);
        $accomodation_id = $INPUT('aid', '4894', false);

        // Accomodation XML 
        $today = getdate();
        $api = 'http://myurl.it';
        $query = http_build_query([
            'get' => 'getaccomodation',
            'upwd' => $upwd,
            'id' => $structure_id,
            'idacc' => $accomodation_id,
            'type' => 'p',
            'mode' => 'xml',
            'ukey' => 'create',
            'l' => $lang,
            'dstart' => $today['mday'],
            'mstart' => $today['mon'],
            'ystart' => $today['year'],
        ]);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($api. '?' . $query));

        // Imposto il locale
        setlocale(LC_TIME, $language);


$nomestruttura=(string)$xml->accomodation->name_struct;
$nome=(string)$xml->accomodation->name;

$title=$nomestruttura." ".$nome;

    }   
  return $title;
         }
```

This finally Works!